# Ms Access file created in 32 bit using in 64 bit version

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, microsoft-access

I have an access database that was created in a 32bit version of windows, can there be any problem using it in a 64bit version of MS Access?

Answer (score 2):

If your database is a .mdb or .accdb file you should have no problems. A compiled .mde, .ade or .accde database is not portable between the 32 and 64 bitness as described in [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/c74c7211-499b-4e59-976d-d63e0de9f491/) and [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx).

You will see the error message *The database was created with the 32-bit version of Access (duh).  Please open it with the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access*

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all*. The file format should not be affected.

(*My answer required 15 characters, so this makes it longer.)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is fairly simple, you will probably not encounter any issues. If your database has complicated coding, then there is a high probability that you’ll have issues.

Comment: What do you mean by *coding*? Routines? Views? I don’t think Access databases even support those.